# ocramius/proxy-manager dont work with php 7.0.12

Tags: symfony-2.7

i have some error with my application symfony. one error is Unsupported declare 'strict_types'. Please help me to resolve that.

My php version is 7.0.12
My symphony version is 2.7.16
My Ocramius/proxy-manager version is 2.0.3

this is the link to my server : http://www.kossa.cm

Answer (score 0):

I actually encounter the exact same issue and the only ugly fix I could find to just pass through (without fixing it) is to remove that vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager folder and do not run a composer update (that would install the proxy-manager back).

As I said, it is not a proper fix, I'm trying to solve it now.

If you found any kind of information about it, please share it with us ;)

--Edit-- Are you using wamp ?

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem, downgrade your php version to 5.6, because ocramius is not compatible for the momment with php 7.0 and above!